# Change md-icon and md-button on hover

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

Please how can I change both `md-icon` inside `md-button` with the button text to have the same color when I hover on button. Please see example on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mQiuHgYD21J9lWzyCAnL?p=preview)

Comment: The same color of the button color?....Can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: I want the`md-icon` to have the same color of the button text when i hover on it @Hackerman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this to your styles

```
md-list-item > .md-button:hover > md-icon{
  color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

here is the [plknr](http://embed.plnkr.co/UHzgUfKVRfLiNWq3edPO/)

Comment: This solves my problem. Thank you....unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to up vote your answer @Jesus Carrasco

Comment: Glad to help dude.

Answer (score 0):

The following stylesheet will work for you:

```
md-list-item > .md-button:hover md-icon svg {
  fill: white;
}
```